# Terminal.app command on OS X to Copy Files to a Network Location

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

I am struggling to transfer a large amount of data to a network location. I am trying to copy a folder from an external drive, and paste it into a network shared folder. Can someone suggest any terminal commands to perform this? I keep getting different kinds of error messages while doing manual copy and paste.

Comment: The `rsync` program is handy, though be sure to use `-n` to preview and there's some trickery about trailing slashes and what gets copied where.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a command to use?

Comment: I have figured out using rsync -v -r /source /destination

Answer (score 1):

One solution is

```
rsync -v -r /source /destination
```

It's worth noting that you can drag-and-drop a folder from the Finder to the Terminal.app window, to get its path complete with any necessary shell escapes, like --

```
/Users/fred/Desktop/stuff-to-copy 
/Volumes/Remote\ Location/target/folder
```

There are many other command options in rsync, which you can get with

```
rsync --help
```

and more detail with

```
man rsync
```